# Rails form params changing in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

I have a form:

```
<%= form_for(:report_main, :url => {:action => 'exporttoxiccreate'}) do |f| %>
<%= collection_select(:waste, :code, Waste.find_all_by_istoxic(false), :id, :code, :include_blank => '') %>
<%= f.check_box(:q_pripadnost) %>
<%= f.text_field(:amount) %>
<% end %>
```

and this code in controller:

```
def exporttoxiccreate
    @report = ReportMain.new
    @reportexport = ReportExport.new
    @reportparam = params[:report_main]

    @report.waste_id = @reportparam.waste.code
    @report.amount = @reportparam.amount

    if @report.save
      @reportexport.report_main_id = @report.id
    else
      redirect_to(:action => 'exporttoxicnew')
    end

    @reportexport.q_pripadnost = @reportparam.q_pripadnost

    if @reportexport.save
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @reportexport.id)
    else
      redirect_to(:action => 'exporttoxicnew')
    end
  end
```

I want to save in two tables, in two objects data from this form, and I need to separate params to manipulate with. I tried with this:

```
@reportexport.q_pripadnost = @reportparam.q_pripadnost
```

**I want to set q_pripadnost field in @reportexport with some value from param.**

**Where I make mistake?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get params from a form in Rails, it comes in the form of a hash. For example:

```
params[:report_main][:waste]
params[:report_main][:amount]
```

So when you call `@reportparam = params[:report_main]`, you are setting `@reportparam` to a hash, but then you are trying to use it later like an object. For example, instead of `@reportparam.q_pripadnost`, use `@reportparam[:q_pripadnost]`.

You can take a closer look at your variable by temporarily changing your action to show a text version of the variable, for example:

```
def exporttoxiccreate
    @reportparam = params[:report_main]
    render :text => @reportparam.to_yaml
end
```